# How to make this data binding in Ember component embedded in a view work?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

I have a view, and a component embedded in it. I want to pass arguments to the view with the {{view}} helper, and then have the component use that data as well, but it doesn't seem to work. I don't know what am I missing...

Here is the code:

```
App.DisplayView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'display',
    property1: 'property1 default value',
    property2: 0,

    debugProps : function() {
        console.log('view property1: ' + this.get('property1'));
        console.log('view property2: ' + this.get('property2'));
    }.on('init')

});


App.DisplayEmbeddedComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    prop1: 'prop1 default value',
    prop2: 0,

    actions : {
        buttonClicked: function() {
            console.log('button clicked!');
            console.log('prop1: ' + this.get('prop1'));
            console.log('prop2: ' + this.get('prop2'));
        }
    },

    debugProps : function() {
        console.log('this: ' + this);
        console.log('prop1: ' + this.get('prop1'));
        console.log('prop2: ' + this.get('prop2'));
    }.on('init')

});
```

The templates are the following:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="display">
    <h2>Dislay view</h2>
    {{display-embedded prop1=property1 prop2=property2 }}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/display-embedded">
    {{input value=prop1 type="text"}}
    {{input value=prop2 type="text"}}

    <button {{action "buttonClicked"}}>Button X</button>
</script>
```

Then I use the view which has the embedded component like so:

```
{{view App.DisplayView property1='prop 1 value' property2='prop 2 value'}}
```

The output is the following:

```
// this shows data has been passed to the view correctly
view property1: prop 1 value
view property2: prop 2 value

// this shows that "this" points to component as expected, but properties remain null
this: <App.DisplayEmbeddedComponent:ember526>
prop1: undefined
prop2: undefined

// same when I click the button in the component: properties are undefined
button clicked!
prop1: undefined
prop2: undefined
```

As you can see `prop1` and `prop2` appear undefined, and the inputs start with empty value instead of the values I passed to the view.

**What am I doing wrong?** I'm trying to understand this nesting properly but no documentation seem to cover this case of a component embedded in a view.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

properties defined in a view need to be referenced using view.

```
{{display-embedded prop1=view.property1 prop2=view.property2 }}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cahogawa/1/edit

Comment: Thanks man you saved the day. Do you know of any documentation pointing this out that I might have missed?

Comment: Did it actually work, I went to test and passing to the component didn't work, it works in the scope (what I originally tested when I added the answer), but then I created a component and it didn't get passed in, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cahogawa/2/edit

Comment: It worked. The problem in your fiddle is that your component was passed the argument `jack` instead of `blah`. Check it out! http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cahogawa/6/edit

Comment: lol, I love when I do stupid things, 5 hours of sleep isn't enough ;)